# Flags' arrangement may confuse novices

Tags: feature-request, flags, low-quality-posts

[image: StackOverflow's flags]

Novice may think that *it should be closed for another reason* is a flag, not group of flags.
Also, hiding flags in a group may be received as suggestion to use them rarely,
what can lead to misuse *VLQ*.

I think arrangement like this could be more readable:

```
Spam
Offensive
Duplicate
Off-topic
Unclear
Too broad
Opinion-based
None of flags above
|-VLQ
|-Describe the problem
```

I think that *VLQ* and *other* should be hidden, not flags *another reason*.
That would be a clear signal that *VLQ* ant *other* should be used only in special cases.

Comment: Related (but not a dupe, I think): http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/211935/the-flagging-dialogue-from-the-review-queue-seems-badly-ordered-grouped

Comment: Spamming my alternate flag dialog mock-up: http://jsfiddle.net/33xr8so0/

Comment: Wouldn't you expect most people who are flagging to recognize the ellipsis as the standard indicator that there's another level of dialog?

Comment: @Barmar the "checkbox" (or whatever it's called) on the left side of each option suggests that every option is flag.